# Calculate the limit of $\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Let $f(x),f:R\to R$ be a non-constant continuous function such that 
$$\left(e^x-1\right)f(2x)=\left(e^{2x}-1\right)f(x)\,.$$If $f'(0)=1$, then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}$$

**My approach**:

Well I just dont get the idea of how to start, I separated the $f(x)$ terms and tried to solve but got nowhere.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is $n$ in the limit?

Comment: Oops, sorry its x

Comment: @PeterSzilas I thought so to but missed it while editting, I wanted to change it but my edit was accepted before I could do it.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yes i accepted your edit and din't notice the error.(sorry for my bad english I am Indian)

Comment: @Savitar You don't have to demean India for your bad English.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam I am not saying that my english is bad because I am Indian.I am saying I am Indian hence my english is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}x\right)^{1/x}
$$
exists. Then
$$
\begin{align}
L&=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\left(\frac{f(2x)}{2x}\right)^{1/(2x)}\frac{\left(\frac{f(2x)}{2x}\right)^{1/(2x)}}{\left(\frac{f(x)}x\right)^{1/x}}\right]\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{f(2x)}{2x}\right)^{1/x}}{\left(\frac{f(x)}x\right)^{1/x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac12\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^x-1}\right)^{1/x}\\[9pt]
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^x+1}2\right)^{1/x}\\[12pt]
&=e
\end{align}
$$

---

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{f\left(2^{n+1}\right)}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{f\left(2^n\right)}{2^n}}
&=\frac12\frac{e^{2^{n+1}}-1}{e^{2^n}-1}\\
&=\frac{e^{2^n}+1}2
\end{align}
$$
This means that $\frac{f\left(2^n\right)}{2^n}$ is increasing for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $f'(0)=1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to-\infty}\frac{f\!\left(2^n\right)}{2^n}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\left(\frac{f(2^n)}{2^n}\right)^{1/2^n}\ge1
$$
This means that, should it exist,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}\ge1
$$
In particular, the limit is not $0$.

Comment: If for the same fuction the same limit tending to 0 then should there be some modification in the approach or i can do it by the same approach

Comment: @Savitar: I have added a section to show that the limit must be at least $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
f(2x) = \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^x - 1}f(x) = (e^x + 1)f(x)
$$

Let $L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}$, supposing that this  limit exists.  Note that
$$
L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{f(2x)}{2x}\right)^{1/(2x)} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{e^{x} + 1}{2}\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/(2x)} = \\
\sqrt{
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{e^{x} + 1}{2}\right)^{1/x}  \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}} = 
\sqrt{eL}
$$
Conclude that if the limit exists *and is non-zero*, it must be the case that $L = e$.

The fact that $f'(0) = 1$ tells us that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = 1
$$
but I'm not sure how this is relevant.

---

Note: Let $x_0 > 0$ be such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$. 
Because $f(2x)/f(x) = e^x + 1$, we can conclude that (again, assuming the limit exists)
$$
L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{f(2^nx_0)}{2^nx_0}\right)^{1/(2^nx_0)} \geq\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{[e^{x_0} + 1]^{2^n}f(x_0)}{2^nx_0}\right)^{1/(2^nx_0)}
$$
So it suffices to show that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\frac{[e^{x_0} + 1]^{m}}{m}\right)^{1/m} = e^{x_0} + 1 > 0
$$

Comment: I have 2 options for the given problem and that are $e^{-2}$ and $e^{1/2}$ and i dont know what the answer is.

Comment: My answer just told you that $e^{1/2}$ is the correct answer

Comment: The above just tells you which one it has to be.

Comment: yes i know just telling you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You have still to show (i) $L$ does exist (i.e., the limit exists), and (ii) it's not $0$ -- don't you?

Comment: @Savitar Oh.  Well, now you know.

Comment: @ClementC. you're right, I forgot to show $L \neq 0$.  Honestly not sure what to do there.  It does seem that this was sufficient for the asker's purposes, though.

Comment: $L=\sqrt{eL}$ implies that $L=0$ or $L=e$, not that $L=e^{1/2}$...

Comment: @zipirovich you're right...

Answer (score 1):

From the equation $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1}f(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{e^x-1}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1}\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-1}{e^{\frac{x}{2^2}}-1}f(\frac{x}{2^2})$$

By induction $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^{\frac{x}{2^n}}-1}f(\frac{x}{2^n})$$

From $f(2x)=(e^x+1)f(x)$, we can see that $f(0)=0$. Thus letting $n \to \infty$ on both sides of the above equation we have $$f(x)=(e^x-1)\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(\frac{x}{2^n})}{e^{\frac{x}{2^n}}-1}=e^x-1$$

Then you see that the limit is $e$.